# Filling some QTableWidgetItems with QString from file

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, settext, qtablewidgetitem

I'm trying to fill a QTableWidget from a file that was exported by my program, but when I try to set text to the table cells they just ignore me, nothing happens.

```
void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_Project_triggered()
{
    QString line, fileName;
    fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Project"), "", tr("Project Files (*.project)"));

    if(!fileName.isEmpty()){

        QFile file(fileName);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) return;
        QTextStream in(&file);

        for(int i=0;i<ui->code->rowCount();i++){ // goes through table rows
            for(int j=0;j<ui->code->columnCount();j++){ // through table columns

                ui->code->setCurrentCell(i,j);
                QTableWidgetItem *cell = ui->code->currentItem();
                in >> line;

                if(!line.isEmpty()){
                    cell = new QTableWidgetItem(line); // relates the pointer to a new object, because the table is empty.
                    ui->errorlog->append(line); // just for checking if the string is correct visually.
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

The errorlog object shows on the screen the correct values opened from the file, however the table is not filled. Any problems found?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
cell = new QTableWidgetItem(line);
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Assigning the `cell` doesn't change anything in the table – `cell` is just a local variable, overwriting it doesn't have any effect elsewhere.

You (probably) want to do something like this instead:

```
cell->setText(line);
```

Or (if you don't really need to change the current item):

```
ui->code->item(i,j)->setText(line);
```

If those give you a segfault, it's that you haven't set the table's widget items yet. In that case, you should do something like:

```
QTableWidgetItem *cell = ui->code->item(i,j);
if (!cell) {
  cell = new QTableWidgetItem;
  ui->code->setItem(i,j,cell);
}

if (!line.isEmpty()) {
  cell->setText(line);
}
```

This will populate all the cells with `QTableWidgetItem`s the first time this function is called, and reuse them subsequently.

Comment: I tried it before and it doesn't work either, I think the problem is getting the pointer from the table, but I don't know how to do it right... And cell is a pointer, shouldn't it affect the QTableWidget?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? `cell` is a local variable. If you assign to cell, you change that local variable, you don't change anything about what cell (used to) point to, and you don't change anything in other objects.

Comment: I mean it just doesn't set any text to any cell.

Comment: It does here with a simple test. Are you sure you initialized the cell items beforehand (edited to cover that case)?

Comment: What do you mean if I initialized the cells? Do I have to put "" in every cell before running the program?

Comment: No, I mean what I did in the last part of the code above. You need to set each cell's item.