# Qt how to insert string inside a cell in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, insert, qstring, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Possible duplicate:
[Filling some QTableWidgetItems with QString from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453343/filling-some-qtablewidgetitems-with-qstring-from-file)

1. How to insert rows at run time in a QTableWidget?
2. How to insert hard coded strings in the cells of this QTableWidget?

Here's what I tried before getting stuck...
I have inserted the QTableWidget using the Qt designer.

the code:
mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /*add stuff inside the table view*/
    QString line = "hello";
    for(int i=0; i<ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0; j<ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); j++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *pCell = ui->tableWidget->item(i, j);
            if(!pCell)
            {
                pCell = new QTableWidgetItem;
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, pCell);
            }
            if(!line.isEmpty())
                pCell->setText(line);
        }
    }
#if 0
    const int rowAdder = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(rowAdder);
    QString str = "hello";
    ui->tableWidget->
#endif
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Can you write down what the current achievement, i.e. actual output is? Does it remain empty becaues the initial column and row count are zero or so? Were the row and column counts set properly in QtDesigner? On a site note, `if(!line.isEmpty())` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you @Laszlo Papp, I removed the `if(!line.isEmpty())` .
Also, I found that I had missed creating rows and columns, until now i had only created 3 columns using the designer. I added two statements for adding rows and columns. And it worked.
Here is the code:-

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    /*add rows and columns*/
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(10);
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(3);

    /*add stuff inside the table view*/
    QString line = "hello";
    for(int i=0; i<ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0; j<ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); j++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *pCell = ui->tableWidget->item(i, j);
            if(!pCell)
            {
                pCell = new QTableWidgetItem;
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, pCell);
            }
            pCell->setText(line);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the expected and obtained output.